# In which cases does App Engine search raise a TransientError?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I've seen the `Index.search` method raise a `search.TransientError`, and I know other methods may raise such errors as well, but in the documentation, I'm seeing code like this:

```
# Index the document.
try:
    index.put(doc)
except search.PutError, e:
    result = e.results[0]
    if result.code == search.OperationResult.TRANSIENT_ERROR:
        # possibly retry indexing result.object_id
except search.Error, e:
    # possibly log the failure
```

When are checks like this necessary, and in which cases can I rely on `search.TransientError`being raised?

Looking through the source code, it looks like some (if not all) methods of the `Index` class use the `_MakeSyncSearchServiceCall` function, which, if anything goes wrong, calls `_ToSearchError` passing in an exception. This error returns an element from the `_ERROR_MAP` dictionary, based on the `application_error property of the error. This dictionary contains the`TransientError`, so it is clear that it is raised in certain cases.

So, when is it necessary to check `result.code`, and what other errors could be raised in cases that are out of my control?

Comment: Were you able to figure anything more out about this?